# Printing Extra Attribute Values Onto Product Page

Tags: attributes

I'm just wondering how I can add extra information about a product onto the front end?

I want to add attribute information as well as the description to my product page.

Example here:

http://nickmaddren.com/used-cars.html/focus.html

Will the code that prints this to the front end be in the template file I am using or will it be in a Magento core file?

Thanks, Nick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you should simply be able to call that attribute on the product view template on you page.

```
$_product->getData('your_attribute');
$_product->getYourAttribute();
```